# How do you automatically quote long strings in emacs at line breaks ala pycharm

Tags: emacs, editor, emacs24

Although I really like PyCharm, but I want to really learn how to do this in emacs. When I am cleaning up pep8 violations especially long lines violations I really appreciate PyCharm's ability to automatically quote the end of the line or add anything else that I usually do manually in emacs. Is there a plugin in emacs that does the same? Eg:

From:

```
output_string += '<table border="1"><tr><th>Column</th> <th>Type</th> <th>Required</th></tr>'
```

It will automatically add the end of line required when I do a new line into:

```
output_string += '<table border="1"><tr><th>Column</th> <th>Type</th> ' \ 
88                           '<th>Required</th></tr>'
```

Comment: Made a feature request at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1235127

Comment: BTW why care to add a newline, why not let Emacs do that the way `auto-fill` does in text modes - just with the backslash added here?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your setup:

```
(defun python-newline ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((char (car (inside-string?))))
    (if char
      (progn
        (insert (format "%c \\" char))
        (newline-and-indent)
        (insert (format "%c" char)))
      (newline))))

(add-hook
 'python-mode-hook
 (lambda()
   ;; ...
   (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'python-newline)))

(defun inside-string? ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((p (nth 8 (syntax-ppss))))
    (memq (char-after p) '(?\" ?\'))))
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works, just that now it would be nice if it would be context sensitive as in inside braces or parenthesis it will not add a "\" character as it's not needed

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. Also `python-newline` is bound to `C-m`. If you
want nothing done, you could just `C-j`.